# iOS Facebook login doesn't work

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I have an app, for iOS5 and above, in which I am trying to set up Facebook login. All works fine when there is a Facebook account integrated in the phone. If it is not, it doesn't work. This is even if the Facebook app is installed.

When the app is installed, it opens the app, asks me permission to access the appropriate user data and returns to my app with no result. It the same when it isn't installed. Safari is opened, asks me for authorization, returns, and nothing.

I followed all the steps mentioned in the Facebook Login tutorial. Is this a problem only I am facing?

EDIT: This is the requested code:

I open a session like so:

```
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {

    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"email",
                        nil];

    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                          allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState state,
                                                         NSError *error) {
                                         [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                             state:state
                                                             error:error];
                                     }];
}
```

And when it returns, I guess this method must be called. but it isn't:

```
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                  state:(FBSessionState) state
                  error:(NSError *)error
{

    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
            if (!error) {
                // We have a valid session
                NSLog(@"session opened");
                FBRequest *me = [FBRequest requestForMe];
                __block NSString *username = nil;

                [me startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                             id result,
                                             NSError *error) {
                    NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *my = (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *) result;
                  //  NSLog(@"User session found: %@", my.username);
                    username = my.username;
                }];

            // /fb_access/:access_token

        }
        break;
    case FBSessionStateClosed:

        if (!error) {
            // We have a valid session
            NSLog(@"User session closed");

        }

    case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
         NSLog(@"login failed, %@", error);
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 postNotificationName:FBSessionStateChangedNotification
 object:session];

if (error) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Error"
                              message:error.localizedDescription
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide the code , where have you put this condition and how ?

Comment: Posted the code. Hope it helps.

Comment: Check Create a Facebook App step no 4:Now, you need to set the Bundle Identifier and configure your Facebook application to support login from an iOS application.

Click on the checkmark next to “Native iOS App” and supply your Bundle Identifier in the “Bundle ID” field. In addition, make sure the Facebook Login radio button is set to “Enabled”.

Comment: Done all that. No change. :/

Comment: Yes. Kalpesh is right. Also add below key-value pair in your plist.

1. Add Field (key) FacebookAppID - (value) fbID 
2. Add Field - URL Types (key)
3. Add 2 Field in URL Types - 
3.1 (key) URL Identifier - (value) (i.e. YourApplication name)
3.2 (key)-URL Schemes
4. Add Field in URL Schemes (key) -  (value) fb(fbID)   (e.g. fb557354324264278)

Comment: and also add this method  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    // attempt to extract a token from the url
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url]; 
} into your appdelgate

Comment: Whoa! Those two suggestions worked! Thanks guys. Thanks a bunch. :) Please post those suggestions as answers. I will upvote them, but I can accept only one I'm afraid. :)

Comment: no worries. You can upvote and accept whichever answer worked for you.

Comment: But atleast accept the one , so that anyone faces the same issue, can understand the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following method in to your appdelgate

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation

 { // attempt to extract a token from the url return

 [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url]; 

 }
```

Answer (score 4):

add below key-value pair in your plist.

1. Add Field (key) FacebookAppID - (value) fbID
2. Add Field - URL Types (key)
3. Add 2 Field in URL Types:

   - (key) URL Identifier - (value) (i.e. YourApplication name)
   - (key)-URL Schemes
4. Add Field in URL Schemes (key) - (value) fb(fbID) (e.g. fb557354324264278)

Answer (score 0):

Both answers by iUser and Kalpesh are right. Combining both of them worked for me. Please refer to them. :)